# Abort message: 'fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 102, expected to be unowned, actually owned by unique_fd 0x715aca000c'

Tags: android

My application uses a external Library that perform some network tasks. but sometimes the application crashes with the following logcat:

```
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a22xx/a32:13/TP1A.220624.014/A325FXXU6DWH3:user/release-keys'
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Revision: '4'
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  ABI: 'arm64'
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Processor: '2'
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Timestamp: 2023-11-30 09:51:50.826754560+0330
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Process uptime: 17s
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Cmdline: and.test.com
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  pid: 27088, tid: 27127, name: ged-swd  >>> and.test.com <<<
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  uid: 10563
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Abort message: 'fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 102, expected to be unowned, actually owned by unique_fd 0x715aca000c'
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000069f7  x2  0000000000000006  x3  00000070e0407a40
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x4  0000000000000080  x5  0000000000000080  x6  0000000000000080  x7  8080808080808080
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x8  00000000000000f0  x9  78dcfd4b6b6ee3ac  x10 fefefefefefefeff  x11 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x12 0101010101010101  x13 00000000656829fe  x14 002a3bb2dbe0d963  x15 0000000000000040
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x16 00000072007cea48  x17 00000072007a6c10  x18 00000070df96a000  x19 00000000000069d0
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x20 00000000000069f7  x21 00000070e0408000  x22 0000000000000003  x23 00000070e0407838
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x24 00000070e0407b30  x25 00000070e04077b0  x26 00000070e0407770  x27 ffffff80ffffffc8
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      x28 00000000000fc000  x29 00000070e0407ad0
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A      lr  0000007200752338  sp  00000070e04076f0  pc  000000720075235c  pst 0000000000001000
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  backtrace:
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #00 pc 000000000009235c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (fdsan_error(char const*, ...)+556) (BuildId: 4d6e56b2321dd2889f771482b268b706)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #01 pc 000000000009205c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (android_fdsan_close_with_tag+732) (BuildId: 4d6e56b2321dd2889f771482b268b706)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #02 pc 00000000000927e0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (close+16) (BuildId: 4d6e56b2321dd2889f771482b268b706)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #03 pc 000000000000869c  /vendor/lib64/libged.so (ged_swd_handle_3D_fence_cb(void*, void*)+76) (BuildId: 61cb05cc0d05132ef5cedd90dba410b2)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #04 pc 0000000000007e80  /vendor/lib64/libged.so (ged_worker_thread+160) (BuildId: 61cb05cc0d05132ef5cedd90dba410b2)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #05 pc 00000000000fd040  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 4d6e56b2321dd2889f771482b268b706)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.253 27254-27254 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A        #06 pc 000000000008f5e0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 4d6e56b2321dd2889f771482b268b706)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.259 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.261 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.265 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.266 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.269 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.271 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.275 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.277 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.281  1587-4515  system_server           system_server                        E  Unknown name for ifindex 1024 with more than 284759 bytes of traffic
2023-11-30 09:51:51.284 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.290 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.290  1587-4515  system_server           system_server                        E  Unknown name for ifindex 1024 with more than 284759 bytes of traffic
2023-11-30 09:51:51.293  1032-1032  Zygote                  pid-1032                             I  Process 24660 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
2023-11-30 09:51:51.294   654-654   tombstoned              tombstoned                           E  Tombstone written to: tombstone_29
2023-11-30 09:51:51.295  1587-27260 DropBoxManagerService   system_server                        I  add tag=data_app_native_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
2023-11-30 09:51:51.303  1587-4515  system_server           system_server                        E  Unknown name for ifindex 1024 with more than 284759 bytes of traffic
2023-11-30 09:51:51.305 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.308 27088-27113 GED                     and.test.com                         D  Add worker fail: reach maximum pre-fence count = 32
2023-11-30 09:51:51.309  1587-27259 ContextImpl             system_server                        W  Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner:722 com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication:598 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner:10480 com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run:88 
2023-11-30 09:51:51.310  1587-27259 ActivityManager         system_server                        W  crash : and.test.com,10563
2023-11-30 09:51:51.311  1587-27259 ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        W    Force finishing activity and.test.com/.client_panel
```

I think there are bugs in the lib, but i put the method of that lib in the `try-catch` to handle the exception, but still the app crashes (sometime not always)
i just want to avoid not being crash even if any exception raised.

Note: i use this library method to check some network activity. and i use multi-threading and run multi threads and every thread executes this lib method at the same time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is your question?

Comment: i don't know what happens in the external lib. so i just want to avoid my app being crashed even if that method of the lib raised any error. that's why i put the method in try-catch to avoid the app being crashed. but still crashing. i think android force my app to crash and ignore try-catch